# MySQL Fulltext Search Query Missing Results

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm having trouble selecting all necessary results using a fulltext search query.

`SELECT i.strItemName FROM Item i WHERE MATCH( strItemName ) AGAINST ( 'big*' IN BOOLEAN MODE )`

For some reason, the query returns only 5 out of possible 83 results. I don't understand what its doing. It doesn't list items like "Big Panda", "Big Head Boy" etc.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Thanks
Armin

Comment: don't you want to match 'big%' instead of 'big*' ?

Comment: @nathanhayfield you're thinking of `LIKE`, fulltext only uses `+` (required), `-` (omitted), and `~` (negation) as operators. You can also use a wildcard suffix of `*`, but prefixes are not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fulltext by default has a minimum word length, usually 4 chars (see [ft_min_word_length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len)). Anything below the limit is treated as noise and ignored.

To change the limit, set the new value, then you'll have to rebuild your fulltext indexes to get the words which now fall within the indexable limit.

Comment: Thanks You! I set the environment variable to have 3 characters as minimum, reset the fulltext indecies, worked like a charm :). The only tiny drawback to the fulltext search is that it does not seem to have a partial phrase search.